# Custom themed controls declared in base page

Tags: user-controls, themes, uwp

I have some Styles-Files.

For example ButtonStyles.xaml looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style
        x:Key="CustomButtonStyle"
        TargetType="Button">

        <Setter
            Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />

        <Setter
            Property="Background"
            Value="Black" />

        <Setter
            Property="Height"
            Value="32" />

    </Style>

    <Style
        TargetType="Button"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}">

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I have Pages which extend from my BasePage.
If I want my new Styles to override the controls I have to add this Code in every Page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

However if I have this code in my BasePage it won't theme my controls.

Is there a way to import my styles in every Page without copy-pasting this code over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue with using `BasePage` in my side. It would be better if you can post a sample that can reproduce your issue.

However, to use the custom styles in every page, I recommend merging resource dictionaries into `Application.Resources`. `Application.Resources` is the best place to put any app-specific resources that are referenced by multiple pages in your app's navigation structure. If the requested resource is not found in the `Page.Resources`, the XAML resources system will tries to check the `Application.Resources` property. So if we merged resource dictionaries into `Application.Resources`, we can use them in all pages of the app. And if we want to use some different styles in certain pages, we can specify new `Style` in their `Page.Resources`. For more information, see [Lookup behavior for XAML resource references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187273#lookup_behavior_for_xaml_resource_references).

So we can merge resource dictionaries into `Application.Resources` like following:
(Note that `../Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml` can't be used in WinRT XAML, we should use "/" to refer to the package root.)

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then in other pages, if we don't specify the `Style` for `Button`, it will use the style defined in ButtonStyles.xaml.

Comment: Aaah that's great. I have to do it in the App resources not in the Page resources. Thank you